# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error while retrieve filterdata of softball in cocos2dx

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

I have used softball in my project & want to change it's groupindex while it collide with some type of obstacles....for that i have use below code

```
void HelloWorld::collide()
{

    for (int i=0; i<13; i++) {

         b2Body *body=(b2Body *)node->bodies->objectAtIndex(i);
         b2Fixture *fixture=body->GetFixtureList();


        b2Filter filterdata=fixture->GetFilterData();
         filterdata.groupIndex=-8;
         fixture->SetFilterData(filterdata);
        }
        b2Fixture *fixture=node->innerCircleBody->GetFixtureList();
        b2Filter filterdata=fixture->GetFilterData();
        filterdata.groupIndex=-8;
        fixture->SetFilterData(filterdata);


        world->SetGravity(b2Vec2(0, 0));

 }
```

but getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS at b2Filter filterdata=fixture->GetFilterData();

Don't know what's going wrong in this....

Comment: Where does that number 13 come from? It would be safer to loop using the number of items in the 'bodies' list.

Comment: In my case i have replace for(int i=0; i<13; i++); to for (int i=0; i<node->bodies->count(); i++); still getting same error...

Comment: Are you destroying any bodies or fixtures around this time? Use the debugger to look at the values of the bodies and fixtures involved, you can probably tell if they are invalid or not.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to use debugger for getting values of bodies and fixtures at runtime

Comment: There is plenty of information about that on the net. I really recommend learning how to use a debugger, it's like turning the lights on after working in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Not every body has a fixture (shape). Check that fixture is not NULL before accessing it.

Also, since filterData is [returned by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/), you don't need to set it again. Replace this:

```
b2Filter filterdata=fixture->GetFilterData();
filterdata.groupIndex=-8;
fixture->SetFilterData(filterdata);
```

with this and it'll work fine:

```
b2Filter filterdata=fixture->GetFilterData();
filterdata.groupIndex=-8;
```

GetFilterData does not copy the b2Filter, it returns the filter by reference so it's actually the same object and you can modify it directly without re-assignment.

Comment: I have follow this http://www.uchidacoonga.com/2012/04/soft-body-physics-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-part-44/ here while create softbody every body gets fixture in for loop...still when i check in if condition for fixture then it gives error of EXC_BAD at     fixture->SetFilterData(filterdata);

Comment: See my updated answer. The error is maybe because you're setting the filter data to the exact same object.

Comment: I have changed line as per your answer but this time i am getting EXC_BAD at b2Filter filterdata=fixture->GetFilterData();

Comment: Hey i got my mistake,softbody ball's bodies are type of CCBody.so cast it to b2body now it work properly...Thanks for giving your time